Switching from JPA to JDBC how to auto create flyway migration sql script
If I use the spring data JPA as the data source, I have a tool called JPA buddy in intellj which helps me to generate the SQL query automatically.
I am trying to switch to spring Data JDBC and R2DBC with the below entity as an example
@MappedEntity
public record Book(@Id @GeneratedValue @Nullable Long id,
                   @DateCreated @Nullable Date dateCreated,
                   String title,
                   int pages) {
}

If I have used a JPA entity I can use the JPA buddy to generate the SQL script. How can I achieve the same thing with JDBC for flyway migration?
I don't want to write the SQL script manually, is there a better way to do that?
